# Switch specific Model3DGroup as Visible / Invisible in 3D XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, 3d

I've generated a complex XAML from 3DS. This 3D model has lots of Model3DGroups, each with its own transform. It represents an industrial robot with 2 pieces in its extremes. How can I make these 2 pieces to be Visible and/or Invisible. It looks like Visibility is not a property here. I must switch between those 2 states, and this is going to happen at different time frames and positions. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Didn't you try applying scale transform like zero scale as invisible and 1-based scale as visible?

Comment: Yeap, that was one good solution. 
Although my original scale was not 1-based, so I decided to back it up. So I cloned the original ScaleTransform for backup, and modify the existing one with zero values, because replacing the existing transform with a new zero-scale one, was not working (probably because of the order of the multiple transforms).
Propose it as a solution, Eugene. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying scale transform like zero scale as invisible and non-zero scale as visible.

Comment: are there no better alternatives?